# getting a variable value in an html page and using it in an external js

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi have a php template that displays an html page. in it there is a call to a js file that initializes  some jquery plugins.

on the template i have this code:

```
(function($) { 

 $(document).ready(function(){
     var adlow = <?php echo $jSeblod->disparities_tick_lower->value ?>;
     var adhigh = <?php echo $jSeblod->disparities_tick_upper->value ?>;
     var adtickno = <?php echo $jSeblod->disparities_tick_divisions->value ?>;

    });
})(jQuery);
```

then on the init.js page i call adlow, adhigh and adtickno.
i get variable undefined errors.

the php is returning the correct values. but then the external init file is not getting them. do i need to do something special to get the init file to be able to use these variables?
all i did was just plug them in...

thanks, i am a little hazy on the interaction between these pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They need to be globals for other pages to use them. Try removing the `var`. Or namespace them, which is better practice:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    MYAPP = {};
    MYAPP.adlow = <?php echo $jSeblod->disparities_tick_lower->value ?>;
    MYAPP.adhigh = <?php echo $jSeblod->disparities_tick_upper->value ?>;
    MYAPP.adtickno = <?php echo $jSeblod->disparities_tick_divisions->value ?>;

   });
```

Comment: hi, this is just what i meant. i didnt understand the whole global declaration thing. but balusc was correct as well. neither answer works without the other. you need to declare the globals before init.js loads.

Comment: just so i am clear here. the MYAPP is the new namespace? and any variable i declare with that namespace will then be available globally?

Comment: `MYAPP` is a global javascript object that is being used as a namespace. Since `MYAPP` is global, any variables added to it will be globally accessible as well, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to print them in global scope *before* `init.js` get loaded.

```
<script>
    var adlow = <?php echo $jSeblod->disparities_tick_lower->value ?>;
    var adhigh = <?php echo $jSeblod->disparities_tick_upper->value ?>;
    var adtickno = <?php echo $jSeblod->disparities_tick_divisions->value ?>;
</script>
<script src="init.js"></script>
```

Printing them during `$(document).ready()` makes no sense. The `init.js` already get loaded before that.

Comment: hi, while your answer was needed, (see above comment)... the above really got to the heart of my question, which was about passing the variables. if i could check two correct i would check your answer too.